# CSS Dropdown Interfering With Flexbox

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm making a site for practice and I have came across this weird "bug" (Best word I could think of). I have a drop down consisting of an outer div and two inner divs, one for the circular user person icon and one for the drop down content that should only display when hovered. This is all wrapped in the `topbar` tag. Below it I have a flexbox div, and when I view it in Inspect Element, it shows the div has a mysterious right margin even though I tried and failed to force a margin right of `5px`.

Image:

[image: Dropdown and flexbox]

Additionally, the drop down itself is off the page. I want the drop down to be dynamic in the sence that I could have multiple drop downs and the content of the drop down is under the icon automatically.

Image:

[image: Dropdown when hovered]

I've tried making all the drop down divs `absolute` and `relitive`, none of which solves any of these problems, please help.

SCSS:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto:300,400,700';
html,body,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,span,div,ul,li,ol,table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.bd {
  &.user {
    .topbar {
      background-color: #198ae7;
      font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #aaa;
      padding: 20px;
      .title {
        color: #fff;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      }
      .topbar-dropdown {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        top: -13px;
        span {
          cursor: pointer;
          background-color: #eee;
          padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          float: right;
          i {
            color: #ccc;
          }
        }
        .topbar-dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #eee;
          box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #aaa;
          margin-top: 51.5px;
        }
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          li {
            padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;
            text-align: right;
            &:hover {
              background-color: #ccc;
            }
          }
          a {
            color: #555;
            text-decoration: none;
          }
        }
        &:hover .topbar-dropdown-content {
          display: block;
        }
        &:hover span {
          border-radius: 50% 50% 0px 0px;
          padding: 7px 10px 15px 10px;
        }
      }
    }
    .flexgrid {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      &.flexgrid-vsmall {
        margin: 0px 4.5px 0px 0px;
      }
      &.flexgrid-vlarge {
        margin: 0px 4.5px 0px 0px;
      }
      &.panel {
        display: block;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #aaa;
        padding: 20px;
        h2 {
          font-weight: lighter;
          font-size: 20px;
          display: block;
        }
        h1 {
          font-size: 35px;
        }
        table {
          display: block;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          tr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
          }
          td,th {
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Checkbook</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mcb.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a46aee1aa2.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body class="bd user">
      <div class="topbar">
          <span class="title">MY CHECKBOOK</span>
          <div class="topbar-dropdown">
            <span><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i></span>
            <div class="topbar-dropdown-content">
              <ul>
                <a href=""><li>MY ACCOUNT</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>LOGOUT</li></a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flexgrid">
          <div class="flexgrid-vsmall">
            <div class="flexgrid panel">
              <h2>Balance</h2>
              <h1>$0.00</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexgrid-vlarge">
            <div class="flexgrid panel">
              <h2>Transactions</h2>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th title="The transaction method">CODE</th>
                  <th>DATE</th>
                  <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                  <th title="Type of transaction">TYPE</th>
                  <th title="Entered on statement">EOS</th>
                  <th title="Is a fee">FEE</th>
                  <th>AMOUNT</th>
                  <th>BALANCE</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>7</td>
                  <td>8</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your js code...

Comment: add your proper code here of on jsfiddle. else delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add right property and set to 0 in the next class

```
.topbar-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #aaa;
    margin-top: 51.5px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Additionally add white-space: nowrap to your li elmements to avoid wrap text inside li

```
li {
    padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```